# React native vertical progress bar with animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

Can someone help me how to develop the vertical timeline progress bar with animation?

Answer (score 1):

You may try [react-native-timeline-listview](https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-timeline-listview) package.

Comment: Is there any better package?